# Perl: redirect multi line text to editor and return edited text into variable

Tags: perl, user-input, text-editor, multiline

Is there any way to print multi line text from variable to some editor, that on exit will return the edited text to the script?

Like:

```
my $result = `echo -n $txt | some_editor`;
print $file_handle $result;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks to me like [Term::CallEditor](http://search.cpan.org/~jmates/Term-CallEditor-0.66/lib/Term/CallEditor.pm) is probably a good approach.  `vipe` is available from the `moreutils` package that can be installed using a package manager, but it is not on CPAN.  Term::CallEditor is available on CPAN, and has also probably been picked up by many package management repos.

`vipe` from `moreutils` invokes vi. Term::CallEditor's `solicit` command invokes the editor pointed to by the `EDITOR` environment variable, which is a more *nix-y way to do things; it's what people generally expect.  In the absence of an `EDITOR` environment variable it will fall back to `vi`.

From the `SYNOPSIS` in Term::CallEditor's POD.

```
   use Term::CallEditor qw/solicit/;

   my $fh = solicit('FOO: please replace this text');
   die "$Term::CallEditor::errstr\n" unless $fh;

   print while <$fh>;
```

I like that `solicit` respects the `$ENV{'EDITOR'}` variable, which is similar to how `git` works, for example.

Looking at the code from Term::CallEditor, it's really not that substantial nor complex, but given the module exists I wouldn't see any reason to try to duplicate its handling of edge cases myself.

If `vipe` respects `$EDITOR` too, then it would come down to an assessment of what other features each module provides, and a deeper code review.  Or just pick one and go with it.  I still may favor Term::CallEditor because it is on CPAN.

Comment: Thanks, it seems worth giving a try. Regarding vipe though, looking at `man vipe` makes me think that it uses 'EDITOR' env. Also, I've just checked it: after setting 'EDITOR' to 'nano' vipe uses nano editor instead of vi - at least on my system.

Comment: That's a nice observation. I'm glad that vipe is doing the right thing.  It's too bad that `moreutils` isn't on CPAN; you just have to get it from your Linux distribution's package manager, if it's offered.  Looking at the source for `vipe`, I see that it also respects `$VISUAL` if set, which is a good thing.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I have suddenly found the way to do this. There is a 'vipe' tool in 'moreutils' package. So after `sudo apt-get install moreutils` (in my case the system is Ubuntu) the code should become:

```
my $result = `echo -n $txt | vipe`;
print $file_handle $result;
```

In my case the default editor is Vim (in my system vipe uses editor from 'EDITOR' environment variable, with rollback to vi if 'EDITOR' is undefined), so the text is opened in Vim under temporary file in '/tmp' - after `:wq` Vim command the editor is closed, the temporary file is deleted and the contents return to '$result' variable. Great!

Answer (score 0):

[Proc::InvokeEditor](https://metacpan.org/pod/Proc::InvokeEditor) is another module that does this quite well.